Does it make a difference whether potential difference is denoted as a negative or positive value in an answer, since it's just a scalar?
Does it make a difference whether potential difference is denoted as a negative or positive value in an answer, since it's just a scalar? Sorry if it's a dumb question, I was just a little unsure.

Yes it matters. A (classical) object can spontaneously go from configuration A to configuration B if the potential difference is negative, but will require work to make the change of the difference is positive.

Potential is a scalar and you are free to choose an additive constant in any way that might make your problem easier to solve.
However, in calculating a potential difference, that additive constant disappears and although potential difference is a scalar, its sign matters! It tells you whether you have to do work or whether you gain energy by moving something in the potential.
e.g., it doesn't matter whether you say the gravitational potential at the surface of the Earth is positive or (conventionally) negative. But it does matter that the potential gets numerically bigger (i.e. more positive, or less negative respectively) as you move away from the surface.
